# How to wrap each line in quotes in SublimeText?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Input:

```
boston beach summer figural yellow blue
boston floral flowers still still-life food pink figural
boston horse pink purple house flowers floral figural
```

Expected output:

```
"boston beach summer figural yellow blue"
"boston floral flowers still still-life food pink figural"
"boston horse pink purple house flowers floral figural"
```

The actual input file has 600+ lines, and I'm looking at a quick way to wrap each line in quotes? Does the method involve using multiple cursors? How about macros?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I would use a multiple cursors approach like this:

**Windows**

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Select everything)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Split into lines)
3. <kbd>End</kbd> (Put the cursor at the end of the line)
4. <kbd>"</kbd> (Add the quote at the end of the line)
5. <kbd>Home</kbd> (Go to the first character of the line)
6. <kbd>Home</kbd> (Go to the beginning of the line... like if you have tabs or spaces)
7. <kbd>"</kbd> (Add the quote at the beginning of the line)

**Mac**

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Select everything)
2. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (Split into lines)
3. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (Put the cursor at the end of the line)
4. <kbd>"</kbd> (Add the quote at the end of the line)
5. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (Go to the first character of the line)
6. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (Go to the beginning of the line... like if you have tabs or spaces)
7. <kbd>"</kbd> (Add the quote at the beginning of the line)

Comment: cool, but: how in the name of god I exit this multi cursor mode now??

Comment: Simply click somewhere else.  Or use the arrows to go to the bottom or top of the files and get only one cursor. :-)

Comment: @sscarduzio or press *esc*.

Comment: You can do this with fewer steps. After `Ctrl+Shift+L` just press `"`. Sublime is smart enough to put quotes on both sides of the selected text.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels If you have empty lines, your method won't work.  Sublime is smart... but not enough! ;-)

Comment: @MartijnHeemels that doesn't work with _US - International_ layout. The _US_ layout is fine (I guess you use that one, can you confirm that?). I use _US - International_ so that I can make a _ü_ or _é_ easily.

Comment: @Matt It does work, but you'll need to type a <space> after the double-quote. After all, the computer is waiting to see what comes after the double-quote to determine if you meant to type an accented character. Typing <space> tells it you want the double-quote by itself. I use US International too, though I usually switch to US while programming.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels I know, but then i end up with empty quotes/apostrophes, so it doesn't wrap the selection. Switch is indeed an option, and not to hard either.

Comment: @Matt That's strange. I just tested it before posting my comment and in my case it does.

Answer (score 32):

**Method 1**:

- no multiple cursors
- + best performance (use for large files)
- - slightly clumsy

Replace `(.*)` with `"\1"`

**Method 2**:

- multiple cursors
- + best in regards to usability/comfort
- - slower for bigger files
- - wont work if the file has empty lines

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, `"`

**Method 3**:

- multiple cursors
- + close to #2 as usability, but works always
- - slower for bigger files

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, `"`, <kbd>Home</kbd>, `"`

Comment: Good answer. You can also find `^|$` and replace for `"` . This way  you don't use capturing groups in find nor $1 in replace, but I really don't know about the performance of this.

Comment: @sergioFC, this won't work for the empty lines though. It will insert only one `"` as there is only one position to match at. But you do have a point that in the cases it does work, it is faster than matching the entire line.

Comment: You are right it won't work if there are empty lines. Good point.

Comment: @ndn: I didn't get your first method. When I search for (.*), I get 'Unable to find (.*)' . May be I'm missing something.

Comment: @AniketSuryavanshi, you should enable regex search first if you haven't. For most people it's on by default. You can do that by checking the `.*` icon left of the search bar or by pressing `Alt+r` when your search is opened.

Comment: For me, method 2 is deleting everything and I'm left with only one quote.

Answer (score 4):

None of these worked in Sublime Text 3 for a multi-column TSV file with tab spacing.

I found this worked for column 1:

```
Find: ^\s*\S+
Replace: "$0"
```